# Java error: /Users/name/.zshenv:1: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home

Tags: java, zsh

I've been having trouble executing anything Java-related getting the following error message. When I open up my zsh shell, I immediately see the following message:

```
/Users/name/.zshenv:1: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home
complete:13: command not found: compdef
```

I checked the permissions and I can't see a problem with it:

- system has read & write permissions,
- wheel and everyone has read only permissions

I believe it might have to do with me deleting some a Java-related directory but i can't remember what I did. How can i get my system to a fresh state?

Edit: add system configurations

`~/.zshrc` file:

```
alias python=python3
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH=~/base/phacility/arcanist/bin:$PATH
source ~/base/phacility/arcanist/resources/shell/bash-completion
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(jenv init -)"

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman$
```

`ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home` returns:

```
Contents/Home
COPYRIGHT               jmc.txt
LICENSE                 jre
README.html             legal
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt  lib
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt     man
bin                 release
include                 src.zip
javafx-src.zip
```

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to execute a directory, but hard to be sure or give more information since I can't see your code/zshenv file or see what `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home` is like. To get `compdef` you need to run `autoload -U compinit && compinit`.

Comment: Hi @MartinTournoij, I tried `autoload -U compinit && compinit` but i'm still getting `complete:13: command not found: compdef` when i restart terminal. I updated the question with my zshenv file and Java Home if that helps.

Comment: As you can see from the broken syntax highlighting in your post, you have a giant typo at the end of this line: `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/H$`

Comment: The typo is due to my failure to copy paste from my terminal as it was not fully maximized. I have updated the post but i'm still running into this issue.

Comment: Any update on this, As i'm facing same issue on OS ventura and jdk1.8.0_202.jdk